# Change my CTAGS theme

Tags: c, themes, ctags

I'm using ctags, which I installed in Ubuntu. When I autocomplete something in vim, the autocomplete text is white on a bright pink background. It's quite painful to look at. Is there a way to change these colors? I haven't found a way to do this, and none of the docs mention anything about theme or colors. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. You can change the color using:

```
:highlight Pmenu ctermbg=<color> ctermfg=<color>
```

Pmenu is PopupMenu, the menu tab-completion brings up. To format the currently selected item in the Pmenu, use PmenuSel.

**ctermbg** is the background color, and **ctermfg** is the foreground color. These can be named common color names such as red, green, blue, etc.

I set mine like this in vimrc:

```
hi Pemnu ctermbg=blue ctermfg=white
hi PmenuSel ctermbg=yellow ctermfg=black
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answer by 'mouche' for setting the colors for terminal vim, the following commands can be used to set the color of the pop-up menu for GVim:

`:highlight Pmenu guibg=brown guifg=white 
 :highlight Pmenusel guibg=yellow guifg=black gui=bold`